# Gradient descent parameter calculation seems wrong?

Tags: gradient-descent

I try to calculate the first epoch of a gradient descent.I only have one feature X;X=[1,2,3];
Y is [-1,-4,-7], so the function is 2-3x;so theta0=2, theta1=-3;
I try to predict them with a learning rate alpha of 0.01, and both predicted parameters are initially 0;
What is the first epoch of predicted parameters?I get -0.04 for predicted_theta0 and -0.1 for predicted_theta1.
I calculated predicted_theta0 as 0-(0.01/3) * (0-(-1)+0-(-4)+0-(-7))=-0.04, but it turns negative instead of positive.I expect it to be positive
because theta0 is positive(2).Same issue for predicted_theta1.
What am I doing wrong?How should I calculate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your results. Your cost function is MSE I assume, and it is $C = \frac{1}{6}\sum(y_i-\theta_0-\theta_1x_i)^2$; $\frac{dC}{d\theta_0}=-\frac{1}{3}\sum((y_i-\theta_0-\theta_1x_i))$ and $\frac{dC}{d\theta_1}=-\frac{1}{3}\sum(y_i-\theta_0-\theta_1x_i)x_i$. And, when we substitute, it gives the same answer. So, you're actually calculating them right, don't worry.

But, you're thinking wrong. Gradient descent doesn't always point towards the local minimum; it points towards the steepest direction. And, it might force some variables to draw curvatures around the error surface. Here, since the problem is convex, your parameters will eventually go towards $(2,-3)$. Simulate it and you'll see.